# what is the meaning of 'to be charged' in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

> Within the possible sacrifices, there is the financial sacrifice, which is translated by the price ***to be charged*** or actually paid by the buyer.

Comment: If you are going to ask what something means here, we need: (1) more context about the sentence (where it comes from, who is the author, etc.), and (2) a summary of the research you've already done (i.e., what words did you look up already, what did you find, and why are you still confused?). [This question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/188398/whats-the-meaning-of-get-the-behavior) is a good example of how to ask about the meaning of a sentence that is confusing you.

Comment: The OP clearly doesn't get the meaning of charge in this context. What's your problem?

Comment: @Matt - See our [Do Not Feed the Bears](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1236/do-not-feed-the-bears) post on meta. We are aiming for a bit more context, a few more details, and some signs of research. (Notice how, if you hover over the upvote button, it says, "This question shows research effort," with similar wording when you hover over the downvote button.) Quality begets quality, and a lack of quality can lead to the same.

Comment: Thanks. But there is room for niceness. Saying hello to a new contributor?

Comment: @Matt - This particular user had their [first five questions put on hold](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/87150/s-slm?tab=questions&sort=newest). I was just trying to explain how to have a better success rate. Succinctness doesn't always equate to rudeness; oftentimes, people read brusqueness where none was intended, particularly in a forum where there is a 600-character limit and [chit-chat is discouraged](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

Active: The bank charged me 5% to transfer the money.

Passive: I was charged 5% to transfer the money.

Noun: Bank charges are terribly high.

(to) *charge a price*, commission, etc

Answer (score -2):

The verb 'To Charge' in English is commonly referred to be synonymous to the verb 'to assault' or 'to advance', however one could argue it has a more common meaning in modern English 'To Demand Money'. However charge does have a large amount of meanings

[Charge definition list](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/charge)

It this sentence they are referring to the 'Demand Money' definition. So in the sentence the verbs 'To be charged'  means that the the Financial sacrifice which is translated by the price **will demand money** of the buyer. Now when I say demand it is not a physical or forceful demand but a more legal one that usually doesn't hold the aggression of a more common demand.