# What does “in what" refer to in “in what analysts took”?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> "China has opened the door to imports of rice from the United States for the first time ever in what analysts took to signal a warming of relations between the world's two biggest economies after a frosty year marked by tensions and tit-for-tat tariffs."

What does the word "in what" refer to?

Comment: Could you please add more detail to the question explaining why you find it difficult or confusing?

Comment: Please also tell us where the sentence came from.  [This question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/188398/whats-the-meaning-of-get-the-behavior) is a good example of how to ask about the meaning of a sentence that is confusing you.

Comment: *In what* refers to China opening *the door to imports of rice flower from the United States*. You could rephrase the sentence using *from the United States,* ***which*** *for the first time ever analysts took to signal*.

Comment: **what** is a placeholder there which might be paraphrased roughly as "an action".  It refers to the action of "opening the door to imports of rice....". *China has opened the door to imports of rice from the US for the first time ever, in [an action which] analysts took to signal a warming of relations...*  The sentence could be rephrased "... for the first time ever, *which* analysts took as a signal of warming relations..."

Comment: So **in what** it is rather like a relative pronoun for the action of the verb "has opened the door...", which is not a noun, of course, but a verb. It  is a way of referring to the **thing** that China has done by way of an embedded interrogative clause, while offering an object for **analysts took**.

Comment: *He jumped over the fence in what onlookers said was an amazing feat of athleticism.*

Comment: I found it on a post of a media on the facebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wording "in what" is not a simple unit in this sentence.

The model sentence includes the opinion of unidentified analysts.   Let's look at a version of this sentence that ignores the analysts and simply presents their opinion as fact:

> China has opened the door to imports of rice from the United States for the first time ever **in a warming of relations between the world's two biggest economies** after a frosty year marked by tensions and tit-for-tat tariffs.

On second thought, this version goes a step too far.   It's not the analysts presented opinion that relations *have* warmed.   Rather, the opinion is that this event shows that relations *will* (or may) *become* warmer.

> China has opened the door to imports of rice from the United States for the first time ever **in [an event that signals] a warming of relations between the world's two biggest economies** after a frosty year marked by tensions and tit-for-tat tariffs.

From here, it's easy enough to explicitly mark that this is opinion rather than fact:

> China has opened the door to imports of rice from the United States for the first time ever **in [an event taken to signal] a warming of relations between the world's two biggest economies** after a frosty year marked by tensions and tit-for-tat tariffs.

And, finally, we can introduce who it is that holds this opinion, as well as placing this statement of opinion in the past tense:

> China has opened the door to imports of rice from the United States for the first time ever **in [what analysts took to signal] a warming of relations between the world's two biggest economies** after a frosty year marked by tensions and tit-for-tat tariffs.

Analysts took something to signal a warming of relations.  The phrasing "what analysts took to signal a warming of relations. . ." represents that something.  Whatever that something is (ideas like *event*, *change*, and *circumstances* all seem to fit) is the object of the preposition "in".

Answer (score 1):

In the sentence, *in what* refers to the subject just discussed.

In other words, *in what* refers back to *China has opened the door to imports of rice from the United States for the first time ever*.

---

The sentence can be rephrased in a way that will express something essentially the same, or the same enough to convey the idea:

> China has opened the door to imports of rice from the United States for the first time ever, **which** analysts took to signal a warming of relations between the world's two biggest economies after a frosty year marked by tensions and tit-for-tat tariffs.

---

You can also consider the following:

> What did she do? She ran back into the burning house.
>   What would you call that? A moment of heroism.
>
> She ran back into the burning house **in what** was a moment of heroism.
>   She ran back into the house. (Her doing that) was a moment of heroism.